# unable to open GNOME Terminal using Shortcut

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am unable to open GNOM Terminal in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Version through Menu (after clicking on 9 dots in the bottom-left corner) also using a shortcut key <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

also, I looked in /bin directory - there is no gnome-terminal file inside that.

also, I am unable to open Software Updater from Menu (after clicking on 9 dots in the bottom-left corner) and in Taskbar (top of the screen) there is a Red Dot with White dash line (kind of Do Not Disturb Symbol).

please anyone could me help, I have look other similar post related to unable to open gnome-terminal but I didn't found what I am looking for, please can some help me.

I am using GNOM-Terminal very often.

please help me.

Comment: It seems something is broken. Press Ctrl+Alt+F3, login and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. Do you encounter some error?

Comment: I am on Dual Boot with Ubuntu 18.04 & Windows 10, and if I try to Reinstall Ubuntu, then does it affect my Windows 10 OS with its Files?

Comment: not as long as you don't delete it when you delete your partitions, try reinstalling gnome